Old Android phone(s) as doorbell - app alternative
Setup working right now, but with minor inconveniences:

app: Com Intercom - https://apkpure.com/com-intercom/com.dcco.app.Com/download
app connects using wifi, no accounts, no server/client separate apps
one phone/app configured as Door - shows large button
one/multiple phones/apps configured as Room - shows clock, speaker, view, hangup buttons.
press button on Door phone, all Room phones ring, answer - show Door camera, option to speak/hangup, automatically record short video

Inconveniences:

Room app has to be running all the time in foreground
Room phone has to have screen on, unlocked

Question:

is there another, more modern app, that can run the Room part in the background (as a service, right)? The Door part, of course, has to be always on, that I understand. But the Room part can run in the background and ring only when signal is received.

I was able to find one single other similar app: linkA Bell - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hakaya.linka.bells&hl=en
But this is worse: app in foreground/background, screen on/off (doesn't matter which way) - ring is received only as small notification inside program (there's a bell icon with small number: 1, 2, 3.....) - no sound, no "regular" notification, no message, no nothing.
Paid plans seem to be just premium themes and no ads, no new usefull features.
Login doesn't work (error: unable to send verification SMS)
And one other requirement: app has to work on old phones (J4+, HTC Desire 530, Allview X4 Soul Infinity L and such), old Android (6, 7, 8, 10, 12)
